# "Service unavailable" when sendmail relays through SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, sendmail, amazon-ses

Edit: It seems that when sending via cron, sendmail isn't using the 'from' domain set in the config, and so the message is being rejected by SES as an unverified domain. So the question is now, why isn't sendmail using these settings in the config when running from cron?

This is a bigger issue than this question, but this part seems to sum it up completely.

I have a number of ec2 instances. These use sendmail to relay messages through SES.

There are a number of bash scripts on these servers that email reports when the script has completed.

If I manually run one of these scripts, the email successfully sends. However, if run by cron, I see "dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable" in the maillog.

Sendmail is accepting the message, but relaying it through SES generates this error.

I know the environment is different between cron and an interactive user, but I can't see how just a part of this sending process could fail in this case.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Please let me know if any more info would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You can configure `MAILFROM` in your crontab. Also check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/121121/how-to-change-from-field-for-emails-from-cron) out.

Comment: Thanks - it's the actual script that sends the message rather than cron though. I've successfully managed to change the sender address when using mailx from the cli, but this still doesn't seem to take effect when the script runs from cron

Comment: Please share the part of the script that deals with mail sending.

Comment: I created a simple script to test this....... echo "test" | mail -s "Test"  -S "from=Sender <sender@example.com>” “recipient@example.com” .....works interactively, but not through cron